# Fusion Table Layer Caching issue

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have created a series of fusion table layers and apply filtering to one of the layers in response to checkbox click events.  The base layer of the map contains a gradient applied over county boundaries.  When the base layer is unchecked, the filtered layer loses it's styling.  I have added unique timestamps to all queries to avoid caching, however I get the feeling that these image tiles are still be cached for this situation.  Is there any way to force the google fusion tables api to invalidate a cached image?

Test site here: http://map.inquestmarketing.com/new.html

Unchecking the Other -> Consumer Prospects checkbox reproduces the issue.

This is a pure client app, all of the source is in the single page.

**Update**

I was able to workaround this by applying style filters to the FusionTablesLayer client side.

I filtered for 3 different cases, but in order to apply the styles across the board I could have used:

styles: [{
                    markerOptions: {
                        iconName: "large_blue"
                    }
                }]

in the FusionTablesLayer constructor and the setOptions function.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are anyways to prevent cache the tile data.
Because Fusion Table renders the tile images on Google server, and which takes a few moments in generally.

Also most browser caches the images based on the URLs generated by FusionTableLayer(that means Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a coding problem on your map; you hide [this layer](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S786425duiL) based on that (Consumer Prospects) check box.  If you want it to be displayed don't hide it and leave it hidden.  I don't see offhand why the blue markers go with it.

Answer (score 0):

As per Kathryn at Google you can refresh the tiles by adding a time stamp. Here's a jQuery snippet you can use or adapt for your needs.

```
setTimeout(function(){
       $("img[src*='googleapis']").each(function(){
               $(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src")+"&"+(new Date()).getTime());
       });
},3000);
```

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fusion-tables-users-group/wCLHnyoZRYk/MtLHFZ-o4zAJ

Comment: Looks helpful...but who is Kathyrn at Google?